GARCH model within a system of simultaneous equations
This is a system of simultaneous equations. The first equations is a GARCH(1,1) model with a exogenous variable.

The dependent variable (x) from the fourth equation is exogenous independent variable in the GARCH equation and the conditional volatility variable from GARCH(1,1) model is an explanatory variable in the fourth equation.
I wonder if it is possible and appropriate to estimate the parameters of these two equations simultaneously.

This does not look complete. E.g. a GARCH model contains some four or five equations characterizing the conditional mean, the conditional variance and the distribution of the standardized errors; see e.g. this. Could you include all of the equations here, so that it would be clear what $\sigma_t^2$ is the variance of and what the distribution of the standardized errors is?

If you can write likelihoods as function of parameters, you can estimate them.

Sorry for the incomplete information. I believe this looks way better now.

Wouldn't there be an endogeneity problem, even if I wrote the likelihoods as functions of parameters?

Things are clearer now. You could specify $\mu_{t-1}$ and $\omega_t$ for completeness. Also, $\epsilon_t$ misses a square. Note that you can type equations here, no need to import as picture. That is actually better.
